# how to remove acetone free nail polish remover from a thinkpad laptop keyboard?

Tags: cleaning

I had dried spraypaint on my laptop keyboard and I tried my oxx studio brand nail polish wipes
(ingredients; propylene glycol, dimethyl adipate, dimethyl glutarate, dimethyl succinate, caprylic/capric triglyceride, parfum, propylene, glycol propyl ether, phenoxyethanol, benzyl alcohol, ethylhexylglycerine)

the wipes did get off the spray paint but it left the keys being sticky...
How do I get rid of the stickiness?